# Does the max code size limitation apply to init code, too?

Tags: evm, create, creationcode

Deployed bytecode (i.e. the one returned by contract creation) ought to be at most `0x6000` = 24576 bytes long. Does this limitation apply to

- init code passed on as input data of a user triggered contract creation
- CREATE and CREATE2,

In the sense that their third stack argument, the `size` i.e. the number of bytes to read from memory and pass on as intialization code, should also be at most `0x6000`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Typically the factory contract *contains* the code to deploy. The size of the factory includes that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you for your answer. I agree with your point that typically the code to deploy is simply a fragment of the init code. However, as far as I know it's the deployed bytecode that has this 24576 byte size limitation. It does seem to me that there is absolutely nothing preventing me from deploying a smartcontract with 1MB of input data that is a standard init code appended with some random bytes at the end. The end result will be the same: I'll deploy the same code on chain. But is this legal or does the init code have to obey the 24576 rule, too ?

Comment: Although reading your answer again, the "Yes" seems quite categorical. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: I did some digging of my own and came to the conclusion that the likely answer is actually No.

Comment: Deployment enforces the 24576 rule. Other transactions are limited by the block gasLimit which is larger and variable. Note that the gasLimit is _consumption_, not payload size, so a small transaction that executes a big loop can exceed the limit.

Comment: I'm not sure whether we agree or not ... do we ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the answer is **No**. This makes sense *a priori* in that the DOS attack this code size limitation was designed to thwart was about loading huge chunks of bytecode from the database at very low cost to the attacker. But this problem doesn't arise for initialization code (which is provided in the input data of a transaction or which is gathered from RAM of a smartcontract under execution, in either case no call is made to the DB.)

I'm relying on Geth to substantiate this. Geth defines `MaxCodeSize = 24576` and this number is referenced thrice in the code. The only reference that matters to this question is in [`core/vm/evm.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/926b3e08ba926fa4c9b699dc496daa03be19ffa3/core/vm/evm.go#L455). The relevant code snippet is in the `create` method on line 455:

```go
// Check whether the max code size has been exceeded, assign err if the case.
if err == nil && evm.chainRules.IsEIP158 && len(ret) > params.MaxCodeSize {
    err = ErrMaxCodeSizeExceeded
}
```

It compares the length of what is returned to the `MaxCodeSize`. I.e. it makes sure that the bytecode that will be deployed on chain contains at most 24576 bytes.